# How do I Implement a gsub in JS to replace a cluster of characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, ecmascript-6

I want to write a function that will take a word and then return a modified word where each cluster of two consonants has a dash between them.

For example:

```
function('Internationalization')
=> 'In-ter-nationalization'
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
function insertDash(word) {
  const pattern = /[^a|e|i|o|u]{2}/gim;
  const splitWord = word.split(pattern);
  const dashedConsonant = word.match(pattern);
  const fullWord =[];
  let count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < dashedConsonant.length; i++) {
    fullWord.push(splitWord[count]);
    fullWord.push(`${dashedConsonant[count][0]}-${dashedConsonant[count][1]}`);
    count += 1;
  }
  fullWord.push(splitWord.slice(-1));
  return fullWord.join('');
}
```

However my REGEX pattern can't accommodate whitespace. I'm getting:

```
function('Le Wagon')
=> 'Le -Wagon'
```

When I really want:

```
function('Le Wagon')
=> 'Le Wagon'
```

Any tips, refactors, or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `\s` to your regex, but also remember to return the whole word if there are no matches in your regular expression:

```
function insertDash(word) {
  const pattern = /[^a|e|i|o|u|\s]{2}/gim;
  const splitWord = word.split(pattern);
  const dashedConsonant = word.match(pattern);
  if (!dashedConsonant) return word;
  const fullWord =[];
  let count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < dashedConsonant.length; i++) {
    fullWord.push(splitWord[count]);
    fullWord.push(`${dashedConsonant[count][0]}-${dashedConsonant[count][1]}`);
    count += 1;
  }
  fullWord.push(splitWord.slice(-1));
  return fullWord.join('');
}
```

This way:

```
insertDash('Le Wagon internationalization')
> "Le Wagon in-ter-nationalization"
insertDash('internationalization')
> "in-ter-nationalization"
insertDash('Le Wagon')
> "Le Wagon"
insertDash('Le Wagon internationalization')
> "Le Wagon in-ter-nationalization"
```

You might also want to add more special characters, or better filter only by consonants, since your regex right now takes anything that is not a vowel as a character. Maybe you want to use `/\w[^a|e|i|o|u|\s]{2}/gim` so only word characters are considered.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `replace()` method:

```
/([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])/gi
```

```js
let str = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`;

const hyphenate = str => {
  const rgx = /([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])/gi;
  return str.replace(rgx, '$1-$2');
}

console.log(hyphenate(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
s.replace(/([aeiou][bcdfghj-np-tv-z]+)(?=[bcdfghj-np-tv-z][aeiou])/gi, '$1-')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ivneOx/2)

Here, only those consonant are split that are in between vowels. The hyphen is inserted between the last but one and the last consonants in the match.

**Details**

- `([aeiou][bcdfghj-np-tv-z]+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): a vowel (`[aeiou]`) followed with 1 or more consonant (`[bcdfghj-np-tv-z]+`)
- `(?=[bcdfghj-np-tv-z][aeiou])` - A positive lookahead (allows consecutive matches) that asserts the position before a consonant followed with a vowel.

JS demo:

```js
let s = `Le Wagon
Internationalization
grasshopper
installation
propagate`;
let v = `[aeiou]`, c = `[bcdfghj-np-tv-z]`,
    rx = new RegExp(`(${v}${c}+)(?=${c}${v})`, 'gi');
console.log( 
  s.replace(rx, '$1-')
)
```